# How to store and keep input in arrays and vectors c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

How do I store input in vectors and arrays in c++ from multiple user input? Like if 'sally' stored '10' in my cin >> function and then 'john' stored '11' in another cin >> function what is the correct formatting I have to do using my arrays and vectors? :/ I need to keep those numbers for later how do i differentiate between the two (and others stored later on) when I have to use them

edit:
so i have to calculate bowling scores so once someone enters their name (i have that cout function written) they will cin >> their name and then the code will say "Enter scores" and i have it in a for loop so that it will say first roll score: second roll score: and so on. so whenever they enter in their name and then their scores how do i keep those scores related to their name. and then someone will enter another name once the first persons scores are all entered. what kind of vector or array should i use to store the persons name with the scores? heres my code so far : https://repl.it/@aladcox2000/lab5c
yes i know a lot of the code is wrong but just so you can see what i am doing and how it relates to my question. hopefully this clarifies :-)

Comment: try yourself then add some code here for us to  analyze

Comment: @aladco20, can you post an example input and output for the above case.

Comment: It's really confusing what you are trying to ask here.  How would two different people provide data to the same program via `cin>>`?  are they sharing the same console?

Comment: i edited the question. not sure how to use this website yet so no idea if it notifies you or not :)

Comment: Are those users operating on the system simultaneously? If not, how does the system tell one user from another? Don't expect many people to click on your link. The Internet is littered with broken computers because their users were stupid enough to click on anonymous links. If you want to put something in the question, put it in the question.

Comment: I recommend against writing much code when you have a outstanding problem as fundamental to the program operation as this. The odds of having to throw out the work you've done once you have a solution because the old stuff just won't work with the new stuff are too high.

Comment: ok wont do that from now on. and that is my question. how to i make a vector that will hold both people's info and differentiate between the two?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` - this would let you store the names as the key and the numbers as the value.